# Why is considering a maximum likelihood as a random variable a frequentist approach?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, random-variable, frequentist

In the notes through which I'm working, the following is said:

in order to compute the variance of a maximum likelihood estimator for $\mu$, $\hat{\mu}_{ML}$, we adopt a frequentist approach and consider the maximum likelihood estimator $\hat{\mu}_{ML}=\bar{x}$ as a random variable i.e. $\hat{\mu}_{ML}=\bar{X}$"

Why is this a frequentist approach?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a frequentist approach because we are considering $\mu$ to be fixed. Thus, all the variance of $\hat \mu$ comes from the data.

Technically, a Bayesian would say that $V[\hat \mu] = V[\mu] + V[\hat \mu | \mu]$ (assuming the variance of $\hat \mu$ is independent of $\mu$).

But more over, I think the authors are just saying they are using MLE's, which have a frequentist justification.

Answer (score 8):

Considering an MLE as a random variable is not exclusively a frequentist approach, and indeed, the author you quote does not claim this.  The operative word in the quote is "and" --- we use a frequentist approach *and* consider the maximum likelihood estimator as a random variable.  The latter is not an exclusive consequence of the former.